# Form Validation Constraints with sub-objects in Play

Tags: java, playframework, validation, playframework-2.0

I'm have a fair complex Form that I am trying to create in Play Framework 2.0. Instead of having all of my fields in the main form model class, I have broken it up into sub-objects. This unfortunately does not seem to be working for validation constraints. The binding does seem to work so I do end up with the object being properly populated.

Is there some way to get validation to work on sub-objects. See the following model and view code. The Email Address under the client is is not being validated.

Form Model:

```
public class Inspection {
    // This works!
    @Email
    private String email;

    private Client client;

    // ... getters and setters
}

public class Client {
    // This does not work
    @Email
    private String email;

    // ... getters and setters
}
```

View:

```
@inputText(inspectionForm("email"), '_label -> "Email Address 1")
@inputText(inspectionForm("client.email"), '_label -> "Email Address 2")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the @Valid annotation on client

```
public class Inspection {
    // This works!
    @Email
    private String email;

    @Valid
    private Client client;

    // ... getters and setters
}
```